# Adding contents of several linked lists to a larger linked list and updating it continually

Tags: java, linked-list

I am programming a 2D game in Java Swing. I have created several LinkedLists to hold instances of classes Tower, Entitiy and TowerBuildButtons. After I did this I realized that I want to have a superclass to all of these: Selectable. This is because all of these elements should have the capability to be selected and hovered over with the mouse. So I created the superclass Selectable and an additional LinkedList selectables.

The problem I am facing here is: When I add additional objects to the smaller lists (entities, towers, etc...) I also want them to be added to the larger selectables list. I can think of one solution to this. Creating a new add-method and making sure that when new objects are added, they are also added to selectables list. Example:

```
void addTower(Tower t) {
        
        towers.add(t); //Adding new tower object to the list of towers
        selectables.add(t); //Also adding the object to the list of selectables
        
    }
```

However, I suspect there is a better way of solving this problem. So: **How can I make sure that the selectables list is updated when its sublists are?** or: **How can I make a list of sublists that updates properly when new elements are added to the sublists?**

Code for my linked lists:

```
    //LISTS OF GAME OBJECTS
    
    public static LinkedList<Entity> entities = new LinkedList<Entity>();
    public static LinkedList<Block> blocks = new LinkedList<Block>();
    public static LinkedList<Tower> towers = new LinkedList<Tower>();
    public static LinkedList<Projectile> projectiles = new LinkedList<Projectile>();
    
    //List of anything that is a subclass of Selectable(buildBtns, towers, entities)
    public static LinkedList<Selectable> selectables = new LinkedList<Selectable>();
    
    //LISTS OF INTERFACE OBJECTS
    public static LinkedList<BuildTowerButton> buildBtns = new LinkedList<BuildTowerButton>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Higher memory imprint

I would suggest you create a `Board` singleton.
Then adding a `Tower`, for instance, would be handled by a `Board.add(Tower)`.
This way, you could implement the `Board` in such a way that adding a `Tower` registers it both in the `towers` *and* `selectables`  collection:

```java
public Board add(Tower tower){
  towers.add(tower);
  selectables.add(tower);
  return this;
}
```

### Lazy evaluation

Another idea which would reduce memory imprint but improve CPU usage would be to simply compute your `selectables` on demand:

```java
public List<Selectable> getSelectables(){
  return new LinkedList<Selectable>().addAll(/*first list of Selectables*/)
                                     .addAll(/*second list of Selectables...*/);
}
```

### Note

I would advocate against usage of `public static` variables and go for the singleton, so that you are *sure* that there is *exactly one* way of adding a `Tower` to your `Board`, hence no one can "forget" to update the `selectables` collection as well.

Comment: The singleton approach seems appropriate. I haven't used singletons before, so I'll have to look into that. It seems that singleton is basically a class restricted to only having one instance. Is this correct? I suppose that I should add all the static lists to that class and carry out all interactions with the lists through the singleton class? @vincentC.

Comment: Absolutely. You want to hide your internal game state in that singleton, and allow interactions only through the exposed (`public`) methods. This way, you ensure that internal state cannot have inconsistencies.